# Snap not working

Tags: snap, 19.04

Since (most likely - because it worked on 18.10 last time I intentionally checked) updating to Ubuntu 19.04 I cannot get snap to work. Some of my software was updated automatically via snap, but it doesn't any longer.

Whenever I try to run update a software in the Ubuntu Software it prompts the error message

```
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": exec:
    "mount": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Same message pops up when I run `snap refresh` in the command line. I tried to add `/snap/bin` to the path, but to no avail.

For further information: I'm running a oh-my-zsh terminal and the path is currently configured in `/etc/environment`.

Edit: Re-installing snapd:

```
apt install snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
gyp javascript-common libjs-inherits libjs-is-typedarray libnode-dev libssl-dev libuv1-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
snapd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 13,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 65,5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.38+19.04 [13,4 MB]
Fetched 13,4 MB in 0s (47,1 MB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package snapd.
(Reading database ... 175145 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.38+19.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.38+19.04) ...
Setting up snapd (2.38+19.04) ...
md5sum: /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine: No such file or directory
snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
```

I suppose this `No such file or directory` messages aren't exactly helping in my case.

Comment: Try reinstalling the `snapd` package (using apt). If it fails, please copy-and-paste the entire output into your question.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks, I've tried re-installing snapd, see edit - hasn't changed anything so far. :)

Comment: The `no such file or directory` message seems irrelevant. That file is not on my 19.04 test system either, yet snap works properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR;** *To fix, create /etc/environment.d/, set the path in a configuration file there, and reboot:*

```
sudo mkdir /etc/environment.d
sudo echo -e "PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/snap/bin"\nXDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop"" > /etc/environment.d/60-snap-icons-and-bin.conf
sudo reboot now
```

---

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS aka bionic, kernel 4.15.0-50. My snap was working but I couldn't look at logs, switch channels, save snapshots, or manage services:

```
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": exec:
   "mount": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Turned out the problem has nothing to do with squashfs; I eventually found evidence it had to be an environment problem:

```
error: cannot get logs: exec: "journalctl": executable file not found in $PATH
```

The squashfs mounts are present:

```
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_0000.snap on /snap/core/0000 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/nextcloud_11111.snap on /snap/nextcloud/11111 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
```

I had set /etc/environment this way:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap:/snap/bin"
```

Couldn't see how that wouldn't be working, so I ruled out problems with seccomp or apparmor, modules, missing packages, or snap configuration files.

---

When I'd almost concluded that I was one of two people in the world having this problem, I hit upon an [old post about snap desktop apps](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/desktop-snaps-do-not-appear-in-the-dash-menu-on-gnome-in-17-10-final-beta/2340/13); I modified the solution to fit. Probably there are other ways to make the environment work - [see environment.d manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/environment.d.html). The system sources environment variables from [very different files](https://medium.com/coding-blocks/getting-to-understand-linux-shell-s-start-up-scripts-and-the-environments-path-variable-fc672107b2d7) depending on what kind of shell you're in, or if you're in one at all.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/environment.d
sudo echo -e "PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/snap/bin"\nXDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop"" > /etc/environment.d/60-snap-icons-and-bin.conf
sudo reboot now
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about my question. This is the right answer - if snap stopped working there is something wrong with your path. In my case, I haven't set the paths correctly in `/etc/environment` and fixing them fixed snap.

Comment: Thank you. After researching and trying several fixes this is the only one that actually solved it for me. In my case was with Hyper-V and both Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and also 19.04

Answer (score 0):

In my case, compiling squash fs driver with xz compression support and loop device into kernel solved that error.

Comment: Kind of sounds more like a comment...