# How to install snapd on ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: 18.04, server, snap

I would like to install https://microk8s.io/ on my VPS server based on Ubuntu 18.04 but I've got the following error message:

```
apt-get install snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Unable to locate package snapd
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pre-installed software.

Type `dpkg -l snapd` to check snapd package status. It will show you it is installed, configured, deleted and so on.

Comment: Yes, I try to install `snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.17/stable` it shows me `error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs":
       mount: /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-722623537: mount failed: Operation not permitted.`

Comment: Okay. I searched the error message and i found this. --> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143436/snap-not-working
This will help.

Comment: It does not work either.

Comment: I searched another one.

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cannot-install-snaps-on-manjaro-linux/9615/16

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/snapd-is-not-working-since-downgrade-to-systemd-239-6-2-2-advised-in-the-security-update-on-2019-01-19/73774/33


According to these questions & answers,  one kernel module should be needed.
What you have to do is type `sudo modprobe loop` and try to install snap app.

I think this one helps you. If it fails, type `journalctl -xe` as root to see what is going on.