# Snap Paths Aren't Listed Properly

Tags: 20.04, software-center, snap, paths, snap-store

**Note:** I am using the example of discord but this is for all snap apps that i installed from the software center.

I needed NodeJs for something and had to go through alot of steps as it simply would not install. I had to mess around with alot of files such as bash.bashrc and /etc/environment etc. I have now noticed that snap apps like discord will not open, when i try to uninstall them from the software center or install the executable, i get this error:

```
/snap/bin$ sudo snap install discord
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using
       "squashfs": exec: "mount": executable file not found in $PATH
```

While if i try to open it, i get

```
/snap/bin$ discord
Command 'discord' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install discord
```

#### I know it is a paths issue because:

1. If I open it from the discord folder and run the executable from there, it will work.
2. It is for all apps that are related to snap, i tried Discord and Docker. Other applications not related with snap will open.
3. Snap and its applications used to work fine before and did not give me this error.

#### What i have tried

1. [Installing sqauashfuse0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62051898/snap-is-unable-to-mount-its-squashfs-image-on-debian-buster-crostini)

```
sudo apt install libsquashfuse0 squashfuse fuse
```

2. [Fix, create /etc/environment.d/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143436/snap-not-working)

```
sudo mkdir /etc/environment.d
sudo echo -e "PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/snap/bin"\nXDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop"" > /etc/environment.d/60-snap-icons-and-bin.conf
sudo reboot now
```

#### System Details:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

I saw this paths issue on [snapcraft](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapd-install-refresh-remove-error/11445/6) and they ran the command:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/$(pidof snapd)/environ | tr "\0" "\n"
```

The main thing to notice is `PATH=` which was set incorrectly for me as i had changed `/etc/environment`. I updated it back to `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"`

After that i tried uninstalling and reinstalling snap:

```
$ sudo apt remove snapd
$ sudo apt install snapd
```

After that i uninstalled Discord from the Software Center and then reinstalled it. That seemed to fix it.